# DropDown menu is not aligning correctly in AppBar

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using MUI with react. The dropdown menu is not aligning correctly. I am following https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#account-menu document.

##### My text code:

```
//** A styled component **//
const StyledToolbar = styled(Toolbar)({
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "space-between",
  backgroundColor: "#1e8e3e",
});


//** States **// 
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(false);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);


//** Actual Menu code **//
      <Menu
        id="account-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        getContentAnchorEl={null}
        onClose={(e) => setAnchorEl(false)}
        onClick={(e) => setAnchorEl(false)}
        anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
        transformOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
        PaperProps={{
          elevation: 0,
          sx: {
            overflow: 'visible',
            filter: 'drop-shadow(0px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.32))',
            mt: 1.5,
            '& .MuiAvatar-root': {
              width: 32,
              height: 32,
              ml: -0.5,
              mr: 1,
            },
            '&:before': {
              content: '""',
              display: 'block',
              position: 'absolute',
              top: 0,
              right: 14,
              width: 10,
              height: 10,
              bgcolor: 'background.paper',
              transform: 'translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg)',
              zIndex: 0,
            },
          },
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem>
          <Typography variant="span">John K.</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
        <Divider />
        <MenuItem>
          <Avatar
            sx={{ bgcolor: green[500], margin: ".5rem", width: 24, height: 24 }}
          />
          Profile
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon sx={{ color: green[500], margin: ".5rem" }}>
            <Settings fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          Settings
        </MenuItem>
        <Divider />
        <MenuItem onClick={handleSignOut}>
          <ListItemIcon sx={{ color: "#f50057", margin: ".5rem" }}>
            <Logout fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          Logout
        </MenuItem>
        {error && <span className="span">Something went wrong!</span>}
      </Menu>
```

- If I am using the `anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}` the Menu is starting from the bottom of the window:

[image]

- If I am using the `anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}` the Menu is starting from the top of the window but from the middle of the user profile image:

[image]

For many people, applying `getContentAnchorEl={null}` fixed the issue but for me its not working. I am using MUI v5.10.0

Comment: seems from your code you are not adding correct the anchor of the element you want to open the Menu from. Have a look at this codesandbox i created for you based on your code. Also please add all of your code or create a codesanbox that we can replicate the issue. Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-ellis-cc4qo7?file=/demo.js:1414-1425

Comment: Thanks @Akis. After going though your code I am able to fix it.

Comment: One more observation is the side roller. When the menu is open, its forcing the roller out even though there are enough space we have. I will raise a new question for that with proper screenshot in some time.

Comment: I have added my answer  bellow with the full working example in case it helps other with the same issue. Please consider upvoting and marking it as an answer if it helped solving the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an element to work as a reference, like an anchor, for the Menu to open from it. Or else it will just show in an edge of the page depending the `anchorOrigin` property  settings you specify on the `Menu` component.

```
<>
      <Button
        id="basic-button"
        aria-controls={open ? "basic-menu" : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="account-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={(e) => setAnchorEl(false)}
        onClick={(e) => setAnchorEl(false)}
        anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "bottom" }}
        transformOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "top" }}
        PaperProps={{
          elevation: 0,
          sx: {
            overflow: "visible",
            filter: "drop-shadow(0px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.32))",
            mt: 1.5,
            "& .MuiAvatar-root": {
              width: 32,
              height: 32,
              ml: -0.5,
              mr: 1
            },
            "&:before": {
              content: '""',
              display: "block",
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              right: 14,
              width: 10,
              height: 10,
              bgcolor: "background.paper",
              transform: "translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg)",
              zIndex: 0
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem>
          <Typography variant="span">John K.</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
        <Divider />
        <MenuItem>
          <Avatar
            sx={{ bgcolor: "green", margin: ".5rem", width: 24, height: 24 }}
          />
          Profile
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon sx={{ color: "green", margin: ".5rem" }}>
            <Settings fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          Settings
        </MenuItem>
        <Divider />
        <MenuItem
        >
          <ListItemIcon sx={{ color: "#f50057", margin: ".5rem" }}>
            <Logout fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          Logout
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    <>
```

Here is the working [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-ellis-cc4qo7?file=/demo.js:1205-3239)

Answer (score 0):

Current target was missing in the code. After applying the following code, able to fix it:

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

<Button
  id="basic-button"
  aria-controls={open ? "basic-menu" : undefined}
  aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
  onClick={handleClick}                         /* Need to include this to set the target pointer */
>
```

And remove `getContentAnchorEl={null}` entry from the `<Menu>`. Else it may generate the following error:

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `getContentAnchorEl` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `getcontentanchorel` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```